# Characterization of a helix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, curves

I recently proved as excercise the following fact

> Let C be a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3,$ with torsion $\neq 0$ everywhere; for $R$ an oriented line, the following are equivalent:

1. The angle between the tangent line to $C$ in $u$ and $R$ is some constant $C\in (0,\pi)$ which does not depend on $u.$
2. The normal $N(u)$ at $C$ in $u$ is orthogonal to $R$ for every $u$
3. The angle between the binormal $B(u)$ at $C$ in $u$ and $R$ is some constant $C\in (0,\pi)$ which does not depend on $u.$

Moreover, the existence of line $R$ satisfying $(i)\iff (ii) \iff (iii)$ above is in turn equivalent to:

4. The ratio $k(u)/\tau(u)$ between curvature and torsion is constant, i.e. it does not depend on $u.$

So far so good, and I managed to prove this without assuming anything about the curve $C$ more than what is stated above. An example of such a curve $C$ satisfying $4$ is given by an helix.

> What I also find written, but I am not able to prove myself, is that
> any curve $C$ such that $4.$ is true is necessarily an helix. How to prove this ?

I add that by (cylindrical) helix I mean the curve in 3D space parametrised as $(r \cos t, r \sin t, ht)$.

I want to add that I know cylindrical helixes are uniquely characterized by the fact that they have both curvature and torsion constant, but I'm not seeing how to show from this the equivalence between point 4. and being a cylindrical helix.

Comment: What is the definition of a helix?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin see my edit

Comment: That is a circular helix, not a generalized helix, which is what criterion 4 characterizes.

Comment: @TedShifrin My question is precisely how criterion 4 characterizes cilyndrical helixes

Comment: Man, you don't read. It does not. Cylindrical helices have both $k$ and $\tau$ constant.

Comment: @TedShifrin I read; but unfortunately you don't make any sense. First you say that "criterion 4 characterizes circular helixes and not generalized helixes"; so I ask, how does criterion 4 characterize what you call circular helixes? It seems that you are just calling circular helix what I'm calling cylindrical helix. But nevertheless my question should be clear nonetheless, since I wrote down explicitly the parametrization.

Comment: @TedShifrin TL;DR Maybe then it's actually you who don't read.

Comment: Maybe English sentence structure is confusing. My sentence said that criterion 4 characterizes generalized helices. Anyhow, I am done.

Comment: @TedShifrin Now I understand your sentence, but I was never given a definition of generalized helix in my text.